# Simplygon import textures issue

Tags: stl, blender, fbx, simplygon

it would be great if someone can help me. I'm trying to import a textured model from Blender to Simplygon 8. The problem is that all gone fine except that the textures are not imported on Simplygon so I can't optimize them.

The model is exported to FBX, OBJ and STL but none of them import the textures :(

Thank you :)